# App-style screen swiping on a webpage

Tags: javascript, css, html

I currently have a website with fullscreen background images with text over than can be scrolled through. However, is it possible to make it behave more like swiping an app (albeit vertically) with the eased animation of the scroll?

Comment: u mean onclick & drag it should scroll..??

Comment: Do you mean like this ?
http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/simple-parallax-scrolling-technique/

Comment: Create an Apple-like one page scroll website: https://github.com/peachananr/onepage-scroll

Answer (score 0):

How about using a mobile app framework like [Sencha Touch](http://www.sencha.com/products/touch).

The kitchen sink has a set of [examples](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/touch/examples/production/kitchensink/)